# how do i use MailMessage with MFA or send emails with MFA enabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web, mailmessage

I am making an app with ASP.Net and I am using `Sytem.Net.Mail.MailMessage` function to send emails when a new entry is added to the database, but my business is using MFA on its accounts. I was wondering, whether there is any way to circumvent MFA; without the need to disable it in the first place.

Example code

```
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("email2@domain.com");
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("email1@domain.com");

MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = "New item added";
message.Body = "A new item has been added to the databse and is waiting approval.";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("outlook.office365.com", 587)
   {
      Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email1@domain.com", "Password"),
      EnableSsl = true
   };
// code in brackets above needed if authentication required

   try
    {
      client.Send(message);
    }
   catch (SmtpException ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: If you can bypass it then it is effectively disabled.

Comment: yes thats true but bypassing in my case here is easier then disabling it as all of that is handled by a 3rd party for my business and its now late and theyve all gone home and since all the emails are being done internally from an internal server i dont think there is a huge security risk.